# Chartjs not showing real values (the values are resizing)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, chart.js

When I create a chart with some values, the values are getting resized and I don't know why. Here are images of the expected chart and the reality that's showing up:

Expected: 
[image: Expected]

Reality:
[image: Reality]

- The values in the data are the same
- Every time that I reload the page, the values in the chart come different
- Sometimes the graphic doesn't even appear

Here are my options when creating the chart:

```
var defaultOptions = {
  legend: {
    position: 'bottom',
    labels: {
      usePointStyle: true,
      fill: true
    }
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100
      }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          try {
            value = generateMultilineText(value.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'), 50, 1);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log('erro - callback ticks');
          }
          return value;
        }
      }
    }]
  },
  layout: {
    padding: {
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0
    }
  },
};
```

The creation of the chart:

```
$('#allCanvas').append(`<canvas id="generalChart-1" style="width: 100% !important; max-width: 800px;"></canvas>`);

$(`#generalChart-1`)[0].height = 300;

let chart = new Chart($(`#generalChart-1`)[0].getContext('2d'), {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: tLabels,
    datasets: [{
      label: "Percentual atual",
      data: tData,
      backgroundColor: formatNumberToColor(tData)
    }]
  },
  options: defaultOptions
});
```

Comment: impossible to help without source code to "debug"

Comment: I added now the code

Comment: can you provide the tLabels and tData array?

Comment: Yeah, the error is definitely in your data and we can't help you without that data from tLabels and tData.